# Sending Email from OFT template using excel vba

Tags: vba, email, loops, excel

Good day
The code below generates a unique email + attachment to each line in column A based on other columns.

This means if the same email exists more than once, they will receive more than one email. What I would like it to do is check whether the email exists in more than one line (already sorted) and send them one email only instead (with all the attachments). is this possible?

this is my code:

```
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim rngTo As Range
Dim rngSubject As Range
Dim rngBody As Range
Dim rngAttach As Range

ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Desktop\EBILL\template.oft")
    With objMail
    .To = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    .Subject = "Invoice For: " & " " & Month & " - " & Year
    .Attachments.Add ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    .Display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
    End With

Loop


    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set rngTo = Nothing
    Set rngSubject = Nothing
    Set rngBody = Nothing
    Set rngAttach = Nothing
```

Comment: are all the email address under A2 cell?

Comment: All emails are a result of a vlookup, listing in column (E). so basically i will have for example 5 users, 3 of which are unique and 1 with 2 entries. This is mainly used to send bills to customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working answer. Hope this can help someone with a similar situation

```
With objMail
.To = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
.Subject = "Invoice For: " & " " & Month & " - " & Year
.Attachments.Add ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value <> .To
    .Attachments.Add ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
.Display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
End With
```